# Sort the List based on number of times a word appear in the string

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a List which is

```
IEnumerable<RSPCA.LIB.Models.Search.SearchItem> results = 
newList<LIB.Models.Search.SearchItem>();
```

My searchItem class has got a string field named content. So basically I want to sort list based on the number of time a specific string(term) appears in the content string. 
So lets say my term is "abc", so if one item in the list's content field contain "abc" twice and other one contains "abc" 3 times than I want this one to be before the one which contains it twice. So basically sorting the list based on Occurrence. I have also pasted my search item class here:

```
public class SearchItem : SearchResultItem
{

    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageDescription { get; set; }
    public string content {get; set;} // That's the one which I want to use
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the following code and [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/) nuget package

```
var results = items.Search(x => s.content)
                   .Containing("abc")
                   .ToRanked()
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Hits)
                   .Select(x => x.Item);
```

This should be considerably faster than the regex implementation should that be of importance in your implementation

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
var result = items.OrderByDescending(x => Regex.Matches(x.content,"abc").Count);
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NYvmk1).